# Is it possible to use Python to search for Excel files in subfolders and then list all of the workbooks and worksheets in a file?

Tags: python, excel

I know how to find all of the files within a folder\subfolders. I use the following python script:

```
import os

with open("output.txt", "w") as a:
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'\D:\folder\'):
       for filename in files:
         f = os.path.join(path, filename)
         a.write(str(f) + os.linesep)
```

Is it possible to find all of the excel files in a folder/subfolders and then list the workbooks and their worksheets in an output file?

My expectation of the output would be the following:

[image: Excel output example]

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple python packages available to work with Excel files that will run on any Python platform and that do not require either Windows or Excel to be used. Some examples include 
openpyxl, xlsxwriter, xlrd, xlwt, xlutils just to name a few.

for walking through directories try something like this

```
# Import the os module, for the os.walk function
import os

# Set the directory you want to start from
rootDir = '.'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
    for fname in fileList:
        print('\t%s' % fname)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You could check the file extension, then use openpyxl to get the sheet names.

Something like this:

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook


filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file)
if file_extension == ".xlsx": 
    wb2 = load_workbook(file)
    sheets = wb2.sheetnames
```

Comment: I get the following error when I use your code: "NameError: name 'file' is not defined"

Comment: Here 'file' stands for whatever object is returned by os.walk. You should add this block to your code. In your case replace 'file' with 'fname'